# Find the remainder of the polynomial $f(x)$ divided by $(x-b)(x-a)$ given its remainder when divided by $x-a$ and $x-b$

Tags: polynomials, recreational-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

I am hoping to get a feedback on my solution to the following problem and if there are better solutions I would love to take a look. Thank you for your time.

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with remainders $A$ and $B$ when divided by $x-a$ and $x-b$ respectively, where $a\not=b$. What’s the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)$?

My solution:
$$f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+A$$
And so $$(x-b)f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)g(x)+A(x-b)\;\;\;(1)$$

On the other hand, $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)s(x)+c(x)$$

And so  $$xf(x)=(x-a)(x-b)xs(x)+xc(x)\;\;\;\;(2)$$

Subtracting the first expression from the second,

$$bf(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(xs(x)-g(x))+xc(x)-A(x-b)$$

Moreover, if we let $f(x)=(x-b)h(x)+B$, we have in a similar manner, $$af(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(xs(x)-h(x))+xc(x)-B(x-a)$$

Hence,

$$(b-a)f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(h(x)-g(x))+B(x-a)-A(x-b)$$

Therefore,

$$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)\dfrac{(h(x)-g(x))}{(b-a)}+\dfrac{B(x-a)-A(x-b)}{b-a}$$

And so the second term is the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach:
$$
f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)q(x)+ux+v
$$
Then
$$
A = f(a) = ua + v,
\quad
B = f(b) = ub + v
$$
gives a linear system for $u,v$ whose solution is
$$
u = \frac{A-B}{a-b}, 
\quad
v = \frac{a B -A b}{a-b}
$$

Comment: Ha! This is great!

Comment: Your solution is nice because it's the one obtained using Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @ihf Is there a way to find out $q(x)$ a better way?

Comment: @ihf Thank you but that wasn’t on my mind when I was working on this problem. I like your solution. Very elegant